# Why can an integer variable created from projection not be incremented?

Tags: c#, linq, increment

I've run into a niche behaviour from C# that I didn't expect. Luckily my unit test caught the unexpected behaviour, but I'm surprised and I don't get it on why it behaves like this. I've reproduced the issue with the following code.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var initialCollection = new bool[] { false, true };
    var projectedCollection = initialCollection.Select(o => (initialObj: o, Counter: 0)).ToArray();

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        var objectFromProjection = projectedCollection.First(o => o.initialObj == (i % 2 == 0));
        Console.WriteLine($"For initial obj {objectFromProjection.initialObj}, counter is now {++objectFromProjection.Counter}");
    }

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Since I've added `ToArray` after the projection, I would have expected the counter variable to not be reinitialised to zero each time. However, it is reinitialised to 0 for each iteration of the loop `for`.

Here is the output :

```
For initial obj True, counter is now 1
For initial obj False, counter is now 1
For initial obj True, counter is now 1
For initial obj False, counter is now 1
For initial obj True, counter is now 1
For initial obj False, counter is now 1
For initial obj True, counter is now 1
For initial obj False, counter is now 1
For initial obj True, counter is now 1
For initial obj False, counter is now 1
```

Here is what I thought it would do :

```
For initial obj True, counter is now 1
For initial obj False, counter is now 1
For initial obj True, counter is now 2
For initial obj False, counter is now 2
For initial obj True, counter is now 3
For initial obj False, counter is now 3
For initial obj True, counter is now 4
For initial obj False, counter is now 4
For initial obj True, counter is now 5
For initial obj False, counter is now 5
```

Why does the counter get reset to zero instead of keeping the incremented value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you are dealing with a **value** Tuple. Observe:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    var objectFromProjection = projectedCollection.First(o => o.initialObj == (i % 2 == 0));

    //Always false
    Console.WriteLine(ReferenceEquals(projectedCollection[0], objectFromProjection));
    Console.WriteLine(ReferenceEquals(projectedCollection[1], objectFromProjection));
}
```

Comment: Ok, indeed this does explains the behaviour. Using anonymous type instead of tuple don't work either because property is readonly. However, defining my own type does work.

Answer (score 0):

```
 var objectFromProjection = projectedCollection.First(o => o.initialObj == (i % 2 == 0));
 Console.WriteLine($"For initial obj {objectFromProjection.initialObj}, 
                     counter is now {++objectFromProjection.Counter}");
```

It makes sense everytime loop runs `objectFromProjection` **ValueTuple** is  being created and it's value will be always 1 as `objectFromProjection` will always have 1 element as `.First()` returns always a single element..

I guess this will clarify somethings for you.

```
 var initialCollection = new bool[] { false, true };
  var projectedCollection = initialCollection.Select(o => (initialObj: o, Counter: 0)).ToArray();
  (bool initialObj, int Counter) d = new ValueTuple<bool,int>();
  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
   {
     d = projectedCollection.First(o => o.initialObj == (i % 2 == 0));
     Console.WriteLine($"For initial obj {d.initialObj}, counter is now {++d.Counter}");
     }
```